# Symfony2 parameter with embedded forms

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

**EDIT :** I find the real problem!

I am trying to give a paramEter to a sub-form from the controller. Without this parameter, the form is working perfectly.

I want to show in the select list only users which are not already present in the relation. I have this query_builder:

```
'query_builder' => function(UserRepository $er) use($options) {
                                    return $er->getFormateursAvailable($options['categ']);
                               },
```

And the method:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface  $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'Intranet\FormationBundle\Entity\CategorieFormateur', 'categ' => false));
    //$resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'Intranet\FormationBundle\Entity\CategorieFormateur'));
}
```

For the collection form, so, I have to put this option in the form:

```
'options' => $options,
```

But I don't know if it is true, and I have to define the method:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface  $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('categ' => false));
}
```

(The form is working without this method if there is no parameter.)
And calling:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new GererFormateurCategorieType(), $categorie, array('categ' => $categorie));
```

And then, I have this error:

> Neither the property "user" nor one of the methods "getUser()", "isUser()", "hasUser()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Intranet\FormationBundle\Entity\Categorie".

The relation:

Categorie has this property:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Intranet\FormationBundle\Entity\CategorieFormateur", mappedBy="categorie", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
**/
private $formateurs;
```

With addFormateur, removeFormateur and getFormateurs

CategorieFormateur :

```
    /**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Intranet\FormationBundle\Entity\Categorie", inversedBy="formateurs")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categorie_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $categorie;

/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Intranet\UserBundle\Entity\User")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $user;
```

with setters and getters for each properties.

Comment: Is there a `setFormateurs()` method in the `Categorie` entity?

Comment: No, I don't have this method and it is useless because doctrine generate addFormateur, removeFormateur and getFormateurs and use these method to add and remove each object.

Comment: No it's not useless, if I remember correctly it's used to pass the values from the form to the entity. Please try to add it and see if you still have the error message.

Comment: And what will be the body of the method ? Formateurs is an array collection. Call addFormateur in the setFormateur method ?

Comment: Can you please add the relations between the 2 entities in your question?

Comment: I added the properties of the concerned entities !

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you have to add the `setFormateurs()` method in your `Categorie` entity:

```php
public function setFormateurs($formateurs)
{
    $this->formateurs = $formateurs;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I put this method again, this is the error message :
"Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Intranet\FormationBundle\Entity\Categorie::addFormateur() must be an instance of Intranet\FormationBundle\Entity\CategorieFormateur, instance of Intranet\FormationBundle\Entity\Categorie given in C:\wamp\www\projet\src\Intranet\FormationBundle\Entity\Categorie.php line 140"

But Categorie is on relationship with CategorieFormateur, I don't know where a Categorie is given to Categorie in my forms and annotations...

Comment: As I wrote in my EDIT 2, it seems so roles of the two entities are inversed. I already have some ManyToMany relation in my project and I was careful about annotations...

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative method, wich is not the true answer :

In the repository, I use 
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

And I explode the $requestPathInfo() to get the last parameter and I use it in the query...

But the existing users in the relation are not loaded altough they not appers in the list.

I hope somebody knows how to do that properly !